# chrome opera can't continue downloading file after pause

Tags: file, google-chrome, opera, download, continue

I want to let chrome and opera continue downloading files after I pause, my server allows range. I found that if I use FireFox,everything works well,but if I chose to user Chrome or Opera,they don't send "range" and I can't continue downloading my file. Anyone has some ideas?

Comment: Seen this [post](https://www.addictivetips.com/web/resume-a-failed-chrome-download-from-where-it-left-off/)? it says: `Copy the download link from the downloads page in Chrome and paste it in Firefox. Instead of downloading fresh, Firefox will resume download from where Chrome left off.

Comment: thankyou so much and this solution is good but a little different from what I want. I am writing a php demo to let my file continue to download after I click pause and then continue on chrome or opera,but I found that chrome or opera doesn't even send a range request(my server is able to support this) but firefox works well.I don't know why this happens.

Comment: yes as you said chrome doesn't send a range request. When chrome crashes or you close it manually while downloading something, file that is been downloaded will be deleted.

Comment: thanks a lot and I'm so confused why chrome and opera doesn't send a range request. sad.

Comment: yes actually there are many posts available on the Internet talking about this but none explain it clearly.